# Java.Lang.Exception with Math.pow

Tags: java

I am creating a method that takes two integers, base and power, as parameters and finds base^power. If either base or power is negative, then the method must throw an exception which say "n and p should be non-negative."

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.*;
class MyCalculator{
    public int power(int base, int power){
       if (base < 0 && power < 0){
            System.out.println("java.lang.Exception: n and p should be non-negative");
       }
            int calculator = (int) Math.pow(base, power);
            return calculator; 
    }
}
```

Here is my input:

```
3 5
2 4
-1 -2
-1 3
```

Here is my output:

```
243
16
java.lang.Exception: n and p should be non-negative
1
-1
```

Here is my target output:

```
243
16
java.lang.Exception: n and p should be non-negative
java.lang.Exception: n and p should be non-negative
```

Would someone please tell me how to fix this and why I am getting a "1" and "-1" at the end?

Comment: You haven't posted the code that calls this code.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: `||` rather than `&&`

Comment: It should be || instead of && in your if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
base < 0 && power < 0
```

should be:

```
base < 0 || power < 0
```

Also, you are not really throwing the exception, you are just printing to the console.

You should throw exception like this (If you want to throw one):

```
import java.lang.*;
class MyCalculator{
    public int power(int base, int power){
       if (base < 0 || power < 0){
            throw new Exception("n and p should be non-negative");
       }
            int calculator = (int) Math.pow(base, power);
            return calculator; 
    }
}
```

You might want to read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it could be possible to watch the code that calls this method we could give a closer cause.

Second, probably the problem is that you use "&&" comparator that establish that both parameters should be negative in order to print the "Exception", meanwhile i think you want to use "||" comparator which means that only one parameter needs to be negative in order to enter to the "Exception"